# iOS CALayer masking - always a dark border?

Tags: ios, calayer, mask

I'm trying to create a simple mask for a UIView with the following code:

```
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 80, 80);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0, 80);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

mask.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);

self.layer.mask = mask;
```

The mask works perfectly except for a dark 1-pixel border around the mask.  The best way for me to explain it is to suggest that anti-aliasing is being ignored and any pixel that is not completely transparent is deemed opaque.

I've even tried creating a transparent .PNG with the shape I want, but this dark border still appears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not a regular rectangle, it's a triangle, and I'm hoping to use this method throughout the app using different shapes.

Comment: Anyway, what is the size of the view being masked? And how does it look if you instead of setting the mask add the shape layer as a sublayer (preferably with some color that makes good contrast to the rest of the content)?